# filter() function works outside of hand-written function but not inside of it -- "object not found"

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

I have two datasets -- one of covariates and one of word lists. I want to subset the word list dataset by covariate values using their common participant ID variable `pid`. I wrote the following code to accomplish this:

```
x <- covariates %>% filter(percdemhomophily == "A lot")
y <- demlists %>% filter(pid %in% x$pid)
```

What this does is filter the covariates dataset by a specific variable value, and then uses the filtered covariates to filter the word list dataset by pid. To me, this seems like it should be able to be written into a function so that I don't have to hardcode these lines over and over. However, when I use the function below:

```
covarsubset <- function(listdata, surveydata, survvar, varvalue){
  subsetid <- surveydata %>% filter(survvar == varvalue)
  subsetfluency <- listdata %>% filter(pid %in% subsetid$pid)
  subsetfluency
}
```

When I use the function above, I get an "object not found" error for the covariate variable I'm trying to filter by. But the code is essentially identically to the code that works -- just more generalized.

```
subset <- covarsubset(demlists, covariates, percdemhomophily, "A lot")
```

I don't understand why this function won't work. What am I missing?

Comment: How do you call `covarsubset`?

Comment: subset <- covarsubset(demlists, covariates, percdemhomophily, "A lot")

Comment: non-standard evaluation can be tricky. Could we please have a [mcve]?

Comment: In this case you need `filter({{ survvar }} == varvalue)`.

Comment: Thank you so much @MartinGal, that works! Would you maybe be able to explain why the brackets are necessary in this case?

Comment: Take a look at https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html There you find some explanation on this topic. :-)

Comment: @MartinGal, post as answer? (Or the original poster could write up a self-answer based on your comment ... they might have to wait a little while to post)

Comment: @BenBolker At this moment I don't feel qualified to elaborate on this topic any further than my comment. But anyone may feel free to write a good answer on this question. :-)